# Warning: Format specifies type 'long' but the argument has type 'UIWebViewNavigationType' ( aka 'enum UIWebViewNavigationType')

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, format-specifiers

Was wondering if someone can help me with this error warning which I am receiving in Xcode. I think it has something to do with 32 v 64bit. I would like the code to work in both 32 and 64bit. The relevant section of code is:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    NSLog(@"expected:%ld, got:%ld", (long)UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked, navigationType);
    NSLog(@"Main Doc URL:%@", [[request mainDocumentURL] absoluteString]);
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request mainDocumentURL]];
        return NO;
```

many thanks

Comment: Please post the error/warning that you are getting.

Comment: @akashg the title of the question has the warning...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`UIWebViewNavigationType` is defined as

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIWebViewNavigationType) {
    // ...
};
```

and `NSInteger` is `int` on 32-bit and `long` on 64-bit platforms. Therefore you
should cast the value to `long`

```
NSLog(@"expected:%ld, got:%ld", (long)UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked,
                                (long)navigationType);
```

to make it compile without warnings (and work correctly) in all cases.

Comment: That's it - all working now in 32 and 64 - needed the second 'long' - thanks Martin R